# Pack/unpack matrices into/from N-D array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a fast way to store (pack) multiple matrices (with different shapes) into one N-D array (N does not matter), and then unpack it back when needed?

Here is my quick and dirty solution:

```
def pack(*matrices):
  return np.concatenate([a.flatten() for a in matrices])

def unpack(container):
  shapes = [ (64, 25), (64, 1), (25, 64), (25, 1) ] #Example
  sections = [ np.prod(shape) for shape in shapes ] 
  arrays = np.split(x, np.cumsum(sections))
  return [ np.reshape(a, shape) for a, shape in zip(arrays, shapes)]
```

### Context

I am using `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b` which takes an 'initial guess' parameter x0. Internally, `x = array(x0, float64)` is executed, which means that a sequence of (elements convertible to) floats is expected. If x0 = [ matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, ... ] then exception rises:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Hence all these matrices need to be packed into a sequence of floats and then unpacked when needed.

Comment: Given the constraint, that looks like a good solution, especially if the number of matrices is small compared to their individual size(s).  I wouldn't worry about list comprehensions over a dozen items.

Comment: I measured the time: pack() takes ~5.5*10^-5 seconds, unpack() takes ~2.4*10^-4 seconds. My the algorithm, ~.2 seconds are spent on packing/unpacking in total. So it's not crucial to have an optimized version given the constraint, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most efficient way to do this would be to rewrite the function `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b`. It shouldn't be difficult

You can find the source code here : [github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py#L47)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'd like to preserve portability. Somehow I don't like having a modified (and a version specific) scipy's lbfgsb.py just for this small change.

Comment: I have tried your proposal and hit a dead end: the trail leads to `_lbfgsb` module, which is a compiled extension.

Comment: But why can't you store all your floats in a single list ?

Comment: Because I'm optimizing a cost function for a [neural network](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Autoencoders_and_Sparsity) that has several layers, and each layer's weight matrix has different size. In theory, I can store all float as a single list, but then I have to "cast" parts of this list as matrices (this is what I mean by "fast way"). Currently, these floats are copied between the list and a bunch of matrices, which is not as efficient as it can be.

Comment: Forgot no mention: I also operate on those "matrices with different sizes", e.g. multiply and add them. That's why I cannot use a single list directly.